# On delete move S3 bucket objects to Glacier bucket using lifecycle rules defined in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to configure using lifecycle rules in Cloudformation template to move all S3 bucket objects to another bucket and change their storage class to Glacier?

Comment: Only using AWS S3 lifecycle configuration, you can not achieve objects move to another s3 bucket. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html#lifecycle-config-overview-what) , you can find use-cases of AWS S3 lifecycle configuration. But you can use use combination of AWS S3 lifecycle configuration for Transition to Glacier storage class along with AWS cloudwatch event rule or AWS Eventbridge for move bucket action.

Comment: @amitd Thank you, I'll take a look at Eventbridge. Do you think that Lambdas instead of Eventbridge would be a good fit for file moving operations?

Comment: In my previous comment, I forgot to mention AWS Lambda to execute opreations on objects move operation from s3 bucket. Furthermore, I mentioned [AWS Eventbridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-dynamic-amazon-s3-event-handling-with-amazon-eventbridge/#:~:text=Integrating%20S3%20events%20with%20Lambda,which%20data%20events%20are%20recorded.&text=This%20invokes%20the%20Lambda%20function,logs%20out%20the%20event%20details.) is just the event bus in case you prefer to execute AWS lambda based on certain object event on S3 bucket.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation *can* be used to configure Amazon S3 Lifecycle Rules ([AWS::S3::Bucket LifecycleConfiguration - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig.html)).

However, Lifecycle Rules do not "move" objects. Instead, they change the Storage Class of existing objects.

You would need to find another method for identifying and moving objects after a period of time.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think Lambdas would be the best option for object moving?